# What "thing" were Taiga and Ryuuji talking about in Episode 1?

Tags: toradora

So, this is something I am wondering but I don't remember if this was ever explained. At the start of *Toradora*, both Taiga and Ryuuji talk about something that's hidden and about how if somebody sees it, they would want to see it again and that someday, somebody would find it.

But what is that thing they are talking about? If it's explained in an episode then please tell me which episode, or please explain it here.

Comment: It seems to me like they're referring to 'love' or 'true love' (those emotions basically), rather than a physical item. I haven't seen an explanation anywhere (I took a quick look at the wikia), but it would fit with the genre and it matches the description.

Comment: @TheGamer007 Ah yeah it would make sense, I wasn't sure cause I don't remember it exactly mentioned somewhere, but I'm not sure as I've watched it a long time ago and I just started rewatching it and this was the first thing I was wondering

Comment: IIIRC, it was never explained in the light novel either. It could be intentional, left to the reader to interpret.

Answer (score -1):

The "something" is referred to love. Only, person who can see it are the whole bunch of people wanted to have it. because that's the way its meant to be. its what said at start and end of the super duper series. However, somehow it links to the conversation ryuji had with kushieda , about the ghost and UFOs on the beach house.As, Kushieda wanted to see how ghost looks like. It might be referred to the love we have for those who surround us. as in case of Taiga and Ryuji, the whole time the thought themselves as friends and never realised that was the love which don't let them move away from each other.And at last only they were able to see it as they both craved for it for their life. Both of them missed the love from their family. and found each other.

the ending was very satisfying and letting me down too. As Kushieda and Ami chan, both developed the feeling of love and affection to Ryuji. While kushieda thought taiga needed him more and she was feeling guilty of being trying to steal Ryuji from her if she confesses her love towards ryuji while, Ami was the most mature girl in the school , who believed that Ryuji and Taiga both love each other. And she can't have Ryuji because trying will only give her pain just like Kushieda.

The biggest sacrifice was made by Kushieda, she was betrayed by both his love and Best friend. While, I felt super bad for Ami too as she was badmouthing like taiga but she is always helpful to both Ryuji and Taiga. Honestly, Kushieda able to confess her feelings to both ryuji and Taiga in end episode - Confession. But Ami never able too, she only kept it to herself. And that was very painful.

Don't wait for Season 2, as the story was never meant for next season. Its complete on its own.Also, don't forget to watch the real ending after the finishing song in the series.

Comment: If only you hadn't rambled in this answer...it'd have been a good answer.